# Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request | Close

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, images

Why would **imgur** reject an image upload request? Temporary problem, or a problem with the particular image? I've tried several images, all small (<100KB). The error message is not very informative...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301832/image-uploads-not-working-imgur-rejecting-request-on-multiple-sites

Comment: After more than 2 hrs, I was able to upload images. ([Posting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/283093/6094).)

Comment: Yesterday I had the same error message containing 'imgur', while working on a very long answer; I don't know what the reason is, bt *eventually I attributed it simply to having gone over the character limit*, i.e., my interpretation was that it had nothing to do with the properties of the image proper. Looking at the *post you cite*, of couse, it seems that for your problem this is not the reason. So my interpretation of the error message might be fallacious.

Comment: And I did a similar thing like you describe: compressing an image more and more (I think I tried four times) to smaller and smaller file sizes, yet this did not help with the imgur error message.

Comment: @PeterHeinig: It had nothing to do with the size of a post or of an image. See Emil J's link for resolution (but no real explanation).